# How can I update rows in loop in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have table **users** where I have column **email**. Some of email addresses are NULL and I would like to update these rows with some fake email address but this address must be unique (e.g. testX@example.com where X will be iterated number). Could you help me how can I prepare stored procedure which will update these email addresses?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
declare v_i int default 1;
declare v_rowcount int;

select count(1)
into v_rowcount
from users
where email is null;

while (v_i <= v_rowcount)
do
    update users
    set email = concat('test', v_i, '@example.com')
    where email is null
    limit 1;

    set v_i = v_i + 1;
end while;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this inside (or outside) a stored procedure as well, simply by using an all-encompassing query:

**Table used for examples:**

```
  CREATE TABLE emailAddrs(email VARCHAR(255));
    ...
    +------------+
    | email      |
    +------------+
    | NULL       |
    | NULL       |
    | NULL       |
    | some@email |
    | NULL       |
    | NULL       |
    +------------+
```

**Example: Using a session variable:**

```
SET @i := 0;
UPDATE emailAddrs SET email = CONCAT(@i := @i + 1, '@example.com') WHERE email IS NULL;
```

Gives:

```
+----------------+
| email          |
+----------------+
| 7@example.com  |
| 8@example.com  |
| 9@example.com  |
| some@email     |
| 10@example.com |
| 11@example.com |
+----------------+
```

**Example: Using random and universally-unique data generation:**

```
UPDATE emailAddrs SET email = CONCAT(SHA(UUID()), '@example.com') WHERE email IS NULL;
```

Gives:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| email                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| aac9e54bbc2548058460041da06271f6c5698ab2@example.com |
| 333053729d4879fd61c86c44f7a6bb78441b8436@example.com |
| e93540b16d908840c194890ef6bf4537286d0c8d@example.com |
| some@email                                           |
| af104449c8f45bd30d23085cc6f63607fa3bab0b@example.com |
| d9df7bd9a8fb579b7ee9053d9f2520e58b46b808@example.com |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```